# sequential version of openmp

Tags: openmp, performance

I'm trying to evaluate speedup obtained in openmp parallel programs using NAS Parallel benchmarks relative to the sequential execution. How do I run the sequential version of openmp programs ?

Answer (score 2):

By not turning the compiler / linker switch on, i.e. for gcc remove `-fopenmp` and `-lgomp`.

Comment: Doesn't this give any compile/runtime errors ? I'm yet to try executing them as per your answer.

Comment: No, the `#pragma` instructions for OpenMP will simply be ignored.

Comment: Pleasure. You (as the person who asked) can 'accept' the answer by clicking the 'tick mark'.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set a single thread?

```
omp_set_num_threads(1)
```